# Add setTimeout after completing the all click events

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not able to find out the way to show an alert or add setTimeout after completing the whole click event process. As I have few images and I'm changing each image on click on it and its working fine, but I want to show the alert box at the end that you have clicked all the images, the message should be shown at the end when all the images clicked.

Below is my HTML and jQuery code:

```js
jQuery('.images .sho-img0').each(function(){
//alert("check");
jQuery(this).dblclick(function(){

if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-0")){
  jQuery(this).html('<img class="hole-img" src="images/trex-back-leg.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />');
}
else if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-1")){
  jQuery(this).html('<img class="hole-img" src="images/trex-tail.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />');
}
else if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-2")){
  jQuery(this).html('<img class="hole-img" src="images/trex-ribcage-spine.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />');
}
else if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-3")){
  jQuery(this).html('<img class="hole-img" src="images/trex-head-neck.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />');
}
else if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-4")){
  jQuery(this).html('<img class="hole-img" src="images/trex-arms.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />');
}
else if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-5")){
  jQuery(this).html('<img class="hole-img" src="images/trex-front-leg.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />');
}
else if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-none")){
  jQuery(this).html('No bone Found Here!');
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
   <!--<img class="hole-img" src="images/dirt-hole.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />-->
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-3" style="top:20px; left:100px;"><img class="shovel-img" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-4" style="top:40px; right:80px;"><img class="shovel-img" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-5" style="top:50px; right:445px;"><img class="shovel-img" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>   
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-none" style="top:0px; right:200px;"><img class="shovel-img2" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-none" style="top:65px; right:300px;"><img class="shovel-img2" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-none" style="top:170px; left:200px;"><img class="shovel-img2" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-none" style="top:180px; right:80px;"><img class="shovel-img" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-0" style="top:160px; right:350px;"><img class="shovel-img" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-1" style="top:255px; right:265px;"><img class="shovel-img" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
   <div class="sho-img0 sho-img-2" style="top:320px; right:450px;"><img class="shovel-img" src="images/shovel2.png" alt="Shovel Image" /></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link or something?

Comment: @lomboboo can you please check here http://dev.softdevelopment.net/game/

Comment: I understand what you trying to accomplish.
Generally, you need to make counter, each time you discover image you need to decrease it, when timer is 0 then set timeout and show alert box
If you provide jsfiddle I will edit it to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have provided the link to above comment and also provide the HTML and JQuery, can you please help on this by some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add object containing booleans before your function, something like `isClicked`:

```
var  isClicked = {
    "shoImg1": false,
    "shoImg2": false,
    "shoImg3": false,
    "shoImg4": false,
    "shoImg5": false,
    "shoImgNone": false
};
```

Note you should add it before

```
 jQuery('.images .sho-img0').each(function(){
```

And inside your function:

```
if(jQuery(this).is(".sho-img-0")){
    jQuery(this).html('<img class="hole-img" src="images/trex-back-leg.png" alt="Dirt Hole" />'); 
    isClicked['shoImg0'] = true;
}
```

add similar for every click handler

At the end:

```
if (isClicked['shoImg0'] && isClicked['shoImg1'] && isClicked['shoImg2'] && isClicked['shoImg3'] && isClicked['shoImg4'] && isClicked['shoImg5'] && isClicked['shoImgNone']) {
     alert('bla bla bla');
}
```

Comment: I have added all as you have specified, but it's not working, can you please check here: http://dev.softdevelopment.net/game/

Comment: ahhh, please move `var isClicked = {... }` before the function `function toolClick(e){`. Since this var is re-created every click, thus you've no any history stored

Comment: I have added last if the condition after last if else condition and it looks like working fine, but sometimes alert showing before all the click events, can you please check once.

Comment: I think its fine for me, as when all the bones found then its showing alert. Thank you so much for your help...

Comment: you have the problem, that you add "onclick" listener multiple times for the same element. at this line `jQuery(this).click(function(){`, thus alert also starts multiple times.

Comment: you can click on "arrow up" near the answer and this will be the best reward for me as an answer :-)

Comment: Yes, I understand, thanks again :) and I have approved the answer as well with an upvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167094/discussion-between-dicbrus-and-barjinder).